# Non-trivial smooth involutions of the reals

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions, involutions

I'm interested in certain involutions of the real numbers, i.e functions $f$ such that $f\circ f = \text{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$.
It has been shown [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333609814_Babbage_functional_equation) that $\text{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the only increasing continuous involution, and that the decreasing involutions are the conjugates of $-\text{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$, i.e the $\phi^{-1}\circ -\text{id}_{\mathbb{R}} \circ \phi$ for $\phi$ a continuous bijection of the reals.

An infinite family of smooth (infinitely differentiable) involutions is given by the $a - \text{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, which I'll call **trivial** because they're boring.

I managed to construct the following involution that is $\mathcal{C}^2$ : $$f(x) = \begin{cases}-x^2-x &\text{if } x\ge 0 \\ \frac{\sqrt{1-4x}-1}{2} &\text{if } x<0\end{cases}$$

Do there exist any non-trivial $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ involutions? I haven't had any luck finding any so far.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can’t you just consider $\phi \circ (-\mathrm{id}) \circ \phi^{-1}$ where $\phi$ is a (non odd) diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$, such as $\phi(x)=\pi x +\cos(x)$, or $\phi(x)=\sinh(2x+7)$?

Comment: @Aphelli is correct, it's even necessary: if $f(f(x))=x$ and $\phi(x)=x-f(x)$, you have $\phi(f(x))=f(x)-f(f(x))=f(x)-x=-\phi(x)$.

Comment: @Aphelli Oh right, silly me, and I had the general form to make this easy. Although, if I want the function to be $\mathcal{C}^\infty$, I'd need the diffeomorphism to be that as well, right? IIRC the definition just says it's $\mathcal{C}^1$.

But in any case, that answers the question, thank you.